Can't connect to the right DataSource in Spring Tool Suite
I'm trying to run a Post Method to INSERT into a SQL database, but no matter what I do it connects to the wrong datasource. This is my application.yml:
server:
  port: 9091

spring:
  application:
    name: customer-wallet-service

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3306/mdi
    username: mdi_mng
    password: yyyyyyy
    tomcat:
      validation-query: select 1
      test-on-borrow: true
  jpa:
      database: mysql
      show-sql: true
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
          
myotherdatasource:        
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://yyy.yy.y.y:1433;databaseName=report
    username: usrValores
    password: zzzzzzzzzz
    tomcat:
      validation-query: select 1
      test-on-borrow: true
  jpa:
      database: sql_server
      show-sql: true
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

And the configs for the datasources:
package com.stcm.report.config;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;


@Configuration
public class MyCustomDatasourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "My-First-Data")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.tomcat") 
    // *** NOTE the inclusion of the .tomcat above
    public DataSource primaryDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return createPooledDataSource(properties);
    }


    @Bean()
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourcePropsPrimary() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean(name = "My-Second-Data-Source")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myotherdatasource.datasource.tomcat") 
    // *** NOTE the inclusion of the .tomcat above
    public DataSource datasourceOtherConfig(@Qualifier("secondary_ds_prop") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return createPooledDataSource(properties);
    }

    @Bean(name  = "secondary_ds_prop")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myotherdatasource.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourcePropsSecondary() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    private DataSource createPooledDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        // Using fully qualified path to the tomcat datasource just to be explicit for the sake of this example
        DataSource dataSource = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource)
                   properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                   .type(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class).build();
        DatabaseDriver databaseDriver = DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(properties.determineUrl());
        String validationQuery = databaseDriver.getValidationQuery();
        if (validationQuery != null) {
            dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
            dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
}

I autowire it in the controller and in the service:
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("My-Second-Data-Source")
    private DataSource secondDataSource;

And log it in the service:
logger.info("Using DataSource: {}", secondDataSource);

And it still returns this error:
2024-04-23 15:08:41.143[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9091-exec-5][0;39m [36mc.s.r.s.impl.InsertDeviceServiceImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using DataSource: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@53dbe7b2{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:sqlserver://yyy.yy.y.y:1433;databaseName=report; username=usrValores; validationQuery=select 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; useStatementFacade=true; ]}
[2m2024-04-23 15:08:41.163[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9091-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m SQL Error: 1142, SQLState: 42000
[2m2024-04-23 15:08:41.163[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9091-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m INSERT command denied to user 'mdi_mng'@'192.168.10.156' for table 'report'
[2m2024-04-23 15:08:41.165[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9091-exec-5][0;39m [36mc.s.r.s.impl.InsertDeviceServiceImpl    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Error occurred while inserting device result: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
[2m2024-04-23 15:08:41.173[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9091-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only] with root cause

org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.stcm.report.controller.DeviceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2c675330.insertDeviceResult(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

[2m2024-04-23 15:14:12.378[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(13)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36minMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application shutdown requested.
[2m2024-04-23 15:14:12.393[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(13)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-04-23 15:14:12.394[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(13)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2024-04-23 15:14:12.579[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8212[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(13)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'


No matter what I do, it doesn't pick the right datasource and tries to use the primary one instead. The logged datasource is the right one, which makes it even more confusing.
Update to include the impl:
package com.stcm.report.service.impl;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.stcm.report.entity.ConsiliationInsert;
import com.stcm.report.repository.InsertConsiliationRepository;
import com.stcm.report.service.InsertDeviceService;

@Service
public class InsertDeviceServiceImpl implements InsertDeviceService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InsertDeviceServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private InsertConsiliationRepository insertConsiliationRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("My-Second-Data-Source")
    private DataSource secondDataSource;

    @Override
    public ConsiliationInsert insertDeviceResult(String reportDate, double subtotal, String initialPeriod, String finalPeriod, String nameUser, String createdAt,
            DataSource secondDataSource) {

        try {
            
            logger.info("Using DataSource: {}", secondDataSource);

           
            insertConsiliationRepository.insertDeviceResult(reportDate, subtotal, initialPeriod, finalPeriod, nameUser, createdAt);

            
            return new ConsiliationInsert(true, "Insert success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred while inserting device result: {}", e.getMessage());
            
            return new ConsiliationInsert(false, "Error.");
        }
        
    }
}

And here is DeviceServiceImpl:
package com.stcm.report.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.stcm.report.entity.Consiliation;
import com.stcm.report.entity.ConsiliationResult;
import com.stcm.report.entity.TransactionUrbani;
import com.stcm.report.repository.ConsiliationRepository;
import com.stcm.report.repository.TransactionRepository;
import com.stcm.report.service.DeviceService;

@Service
public class DeviceServiceImpl implements DeviceService{

    
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryPrimary") 
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private ConsiliationRepository consiliationRepository;
        

    @Override
    public ConsiliationResult insertConsiliationResult(//this doesn't fit anymore)
        
        return result;
    }
}

Full stacktrace:

2024-04-24 12:32:08.895[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.stcm.report.Report                  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The following 1 profile is active: "uat"
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:09.309[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:09.352[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:09.749[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9091 (http)
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:09.757[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:09.757[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:09.953[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:09.953[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1023 ms
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:10.073[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:10.120[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:10.238[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:10.534[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:10.989[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:10.996[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:11.020[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionRepository' defined in com.stcm.report.repository.TransactionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7bde704a' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7bde704a': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:11.027[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:11.104[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2024-04-24 12:32:11.119[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m8900[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 



As you see from your log statement, your secondDataSource is exactly what you are expecting it to be. For me the big question is how are you trying to insert data into the database in your DeviceServiceImpl?

I think most likely you are trying to use a SpringData Repository which is auto configured to use the first DataSource. And your Report Table is only existing in the second DataSource

Which repository it could be?

Can you show how you try to insert data in DeviceServiceImpl?

Ok, there it is.

Just one point to mention, there’s nothing confusing about that the logger logs the right data source. Just because you create a data source in the application context doesn’t mean spring would know which data source to use for which repository

The example config by kSp didn't work, I solved it by using this:
https://springframework.guru/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-in-a-spring-boot-application/

You need to configure Spring to use different DataSources for your repositories. Also you need to create EntityManager and TransactionManager for your DataSources. You need to put your Repositories into different packages and configure which DataSources to use for the different packages. Here’s a basic example which I couldn’t test yet. You will need to change the used properties, also I would use custom properties instead the ones from Spring Data to ensure there are no side effects.
Example properties:
# Primary DataSource configuration
datasource1.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb1
datasource1.username=sa
datasource1.password=
datasource1.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

# Secondary DataSource configuration
datasource2.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb2
datasource2.username=sa
datasource2.password=
datasource2.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

Example configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.example.repository.primary",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryPrimary",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerPrimary"
)
public class PrimaryDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource1")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryPrimary(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.example.domain.primary")
                .persistenceUnit("primary")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerPrimary(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryPrimary") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.example.repository.secondary",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactorySecondary",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerSecondary"
)
public class SecondaryDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource2")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactorySecondary(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.example.domain.secondary")
                .persistenceUnit("secondary")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerSecondary(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactorySecondary") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entitymanFactory);
    }
}


I get this error now: Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:47c0f7de-6046-4879-be69-5ed2bbc74457
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3680) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar:na]

You need to add a flag to your jdbc url, I think it’s encrypt=false

I get this: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Field transactionRepository in com.stcm.report.service.impl.DeviceServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:

@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
How do I make it so it uses entityManagerFactoryPrimary instead of the default one it's trying to find?

Does your DeviceServiceImpl has a reference to EntityManagerFactory? Could you also share the full stacktrace?

Updated the OP, also here is the full stacktrace:

Can't post the whole DeviceServiceImpl, only the start fits

Why do you need a reference to entityManager and transactionRepository? Are manually creating transactions in your service class?
